# Facebook posting in cocos2d-x from windows phone 8

Tags: c++, facebook, windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x, c++-cx

Is it possible to share/post on Facebook from cocos2d-x on windows phone. I am writing in C++.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible. You would be need to call your `C# code from C++`. You would find many example/Tutorial Regarding post on Facebook in C# using webBrowser. you just call that function from your C++ code. and for how to call C# function from C++ this ([use webbroswer to integrate Alipay on Windows Phone 8](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/manual/framework/native/v2/sdk-integration/wp8-webbrowser/en)) Documentation would help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the Facebook C# SDK http://facebooksdk.net/ but you'll need some additional logic in order to call the C# API from your C++.

Here is a blog post I wrote on the subject that you should find useful: http://robwirving.com/2014/07/21/calling-c-methods-c-winrt-components/